# Removed AD User, Need to Associate Existing Profile to New Account

Tags: active-directory, user-management, user-accounts, user-profile

**Some details**

- Server 2012 R2 (AD Server)
- Windows 7 (Users Computer)

Accidentally removed an AD User, stupid mistake. Unfortunately it seems the user was permanently deleted (didn't make use of the recycle bin). Also checked the 'Deleted Objects', and the user isn't there either.

I have created the same user again, but it has a different SID then the profile provisioned on the machine. I'm wondering how I bring these two accounts (AD Server and Users Computer) in sync again?

Comment: ForensiT [User Profile Wizard](http://www.forensit.com/domain-migration.html) is one option (there is a free version).

Answer (score 1):

1. Login as administrator and rename old profile under C:\Users
2. Go into registry and delete the user profile's subfolder under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList (On the right side of Registry Editor under the Data column it'll show the user's name)
3. Reboot and log in as the user to create new profile
4. Logout and login as administrator and Copy data from old profile to new profile

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using ForensiT software to migrate the profile. Worked like a charm. A bit faster than the manual process.